# Laravel - MacOS - failed. Exit Code: 127(Command not found) Working directory

Tags: php, laravel, bash

i'm working on laravel project where i'm tryng to run my bash "mdb-export.sh" script like this:

```
$fileMdb = public_path('wcArchivi.mdb');
$process = new Process("mdb-export -D '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' " . $fileMdb . " {$table}", null, null, null, null);
$process->mustRun();
```

this code work well in production, but it doesn't work in local, i'm getting this error:

> The command "mdb-export -D '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cartech/public/wcArchivi.mdb
>   CARVEI" failed. Exit Code: 127(Command not found) Working directory:
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/cartech/public Output:
>   ================ Error Output: ================ sh: mdb-export: command not found

**Where is my script sh ?**

```
"/storage/import/mdb/mdb-export.sh"
```

so maybe is a issue with my configuration bash_profile?

**my bash_profile**

```
source ~/.profile
export XAMPP_HOME=/Applications/XAMPP
#export PATH=${XAMPP_HOME}/bin:${PATH}
export PATH=/Users/diegoduran/flutter/bin
export PATH
eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)
```

When i tried to reload bash profile doing "source .bash_profile" i get the error " No such file or directory"

i'm struggling for two days with this problem i can't solve :(

Answer (score 0):

**i fixed the issue with:** 
brew install mdbtools

**How to check if mdb-export is working ?** just run `"mdb-export"` and check if the system require a parameters.